# Parsley.js não valida quando usa data-parsley-min

Tags: html, parsley

eu tenho um campo de senha `type="password"` que uso o parsley dessa forma:

```
<input type="password" name="senha_usu" id="pass2" class="form-control" required data-parsley-min="6" placeholder="Senha" />
```

mas ele não tá validando certo, pq deveria verificar se tem no mínimo 6 caracteres.
Pq da dando errado?

Answer (score 0):

Pessoalmente, prefiro aplicar o Parsley ao formulário através de Javascript uma vez que o pode ser necessário Javascript para validações personalizadas (ver validações avançadas com o Parsley). Para aplicar o Parsley através de Javascript, podemos usar o seguinte código:

```html
 <script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="i18n/pt-br.js"></script>
<script src="i18n/es.js"></script>
<script src="parsley.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 window.ParsleyValidator.setLocale('pt-br');
</script>
```